# How to validate database is pulling data or not in spring batch since ItemWriter is not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

How to validate  database is pulling data or not in spring batch since ItemWriter is not getting called.

I am following this example where I am reading the data from the table and trying to print the list.

[Read from Table](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-database/)

GitHub link for that
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-batch-examples/blob/master/reading-data/database/src/main/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/batch/LoggingItemWriter.java)

So here is my batch config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfing {

    private static final String QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS =
            "select " +
                    "stu_info " +
                    "from myTable " +
                    "where status = '\"+PASS + \"' " ;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<StudentDTO> itemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("Reached Reader");
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StudentDTO>()
                .name("cursorItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .sql(QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS)
                .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(StudentDTO.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<StudentDTO> itemWriter(){
        System.out.println("I am in writer");
        return new LoggingItemWriter();
       /* return student -> {
            System.out.println("student.toString()");

        };*/
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener listener() {
        return new ScheduelListener();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step stepA(@Qualifier("itemReader") ItemReader<StudentDTO> reader,
                      @Qualifier("itemWriter") ItemWriter<StudentDTO> writer,
                      StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA")
                .<StudentDTO,StudentDTO>chunk(2)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build()
                ;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobA(@Qualifier("stepA") Step exampleJobStep,
                    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobA")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener())
                .flow(exampleJobStep)
                .end()
                .build()
                ;
    }

}
```

Here I can see itemreader and itemwriter is getting called but from item writer it si not going to write method of LoggingItemWriter

```
public class LoggingItemWriter  implements ItemWriter<StudentDTO> {
    public LoggingItemWriter() {
        System.out.println("test LoggingItemWriter ");

    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingItemWriter.class);

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends StudentDTO> list) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Writing student info: {}", list);
        for (StudentDTO item : list) {
            System.out.println("test"+list);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to make sure your item reader is correctly defined and returning data from the table. A unit test can validate that.

Once your reader is correctly defined, then if the writer is not called, this means the table is empty (the reader is returning `null` on the first call).